# Exporting data via External Table - Parallel Not Working

Tags: oracle, external, datapump

We are running Oracle 12c SE, (12.2.0.1.0).   We are trying to unload a very large table via this command:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_ext
 ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
 TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY temp_directory
 LOCATION ('customer1.dmp','customer2.dmp')
 )
 PARALLEL 2
AS  SELECT * FROM customer;
```

Per Oracle documentation, if the PARALLEL clause is used, and you specify multiple files, then multiple files will be created.   However, in the example above, even though the customer table has more than 7 million records, only 1 file is created.

Is there anything version related, or that this is SE and not EE, or something else that would cause this option not to be used?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs: [Oracle Database Editions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55822_01/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC109), parallelism is only available in EE. If you request parallelism in your DDL but it's not available for any reason, your process will remain serialized, in which case it will only use the first of your file locations and ignore any others (per [ORACLE_DATAPUMP Access Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle_datapump-access-driver.html#GUID-3BEF455B-7CEB-4E5D-800A-7000A501A652)).